# Route 53 Routes configuration

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns-zone, amazon-route53

Can anyone help me about how I configure my route 53 DNS to do this:

`https://shortenit.me/` (frontend) `https://shortenit.me/:url` (backend with any route before /) `https://api.shortenit.me/` (backend)

The domain was purchased on namecheap and configured to work with aws DNS

Comment: Your question is too vague to answer. If you're asking what I think you're hinting towards, Route53 won't be able to do it, you'll need to use lambda or an EC2 instance.